# Lightbox Doesn't work if i place it in a subfolder

Tags: jquery, asp.net, lightbox

I am using lightbox to display some youtube videos. When I run it from the main project, it works fine but when i move all the jquery and css into a subfolder "css" "js". 
The link takes me to youtube instead of popping up the lightbox.
Please help.

```
  <link href="nivo-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').nivoLightbox();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you moved nivo-lightbox.css and nivo-lightbox.min.js into a subfolder you need to update the src for each of them to reflect that.  For example if the code above is in the root of your project you would need to update them to point to:

src="css/nivo-lightbox.css"
src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"

Comment: Please provide all the source code for the page you are working on and a preview of your folder structure.

Comment: Its working now..Had to change the default setting in the jquery and give them the path